# How to add text between html tags in a string client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After a call in a library I get the following string

```
var data = "<td>123.456</td>";
```

I'd like to insert some data (a `<img />` tag) after the content of the `<td></td>` and get something like

```
<td>123.456 <img src='path' /></td>
```

How to properly do this in JQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use convert your variable in jQuery object the use `append()` to append `img`

```
var data = "<td>123.456</td>";
data = $(data).append("<img src='path' />").prop('outerHTML');
alert(data)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f65kD/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can append the data you want using :

```
  $('td').append('<img src="path">');
```

Comment: I need to add "img" only in the <td> from my variable (I edit the question)

Answer (score 1):

Working Demo : [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLW2b/)

You can do like this :

```
var imagevalue = '<img src="path">';

var data = "<td>123.456 "+imagevalue+"</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the modified string in a variable

```
var string = '<td>123.456</td>';

//create a temp element with the contents of the given string
var $div = $('<div />', {
    html: string
});
//find the td and manipulate it
$div.find('td').append('<img src="path">');

//get the modified content from the temp element
var string2 = $div.html();
console.log(string2)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9mXEG/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for that, but it's easier to just use string operations in plain Javascript:

```
var data = "<td>123.456</td>";
data = data.replace("</td>", " <img src='path' /></td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/xQh5J/183/

#### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var data = "<td>123.456</td>";
    
    $('#my_table tr').append(data);
    
    $('#add').on('click',function(){
        $('#my_table td').html($('td').text()+' <img src="http://www.softicons.com/assets/templates/softicons/images4/winlogo.png" width="16" height="16" />');
    });
    
});
```